# Spring Data JPA won't find duplicate byte[]

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity hierarchy mapped along 3 classes, like below:

**Event.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "department_name", nullable = false)
    private Department department;

    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "business_identifier", nullable = false)
    private byte[] businessIdentifier;

    @Embedded
    private AbstractEventInformation eventInformation;

    public Event(
        final Department department,
        final AbstractEventInformation eventInformation
    )
    {
        this.department = department;
        this.eventInformation = eventInformation;
    }

    @PrePersist
    public void saveBusinessIdentifier()
    {
        this.businessIdentifier = eventInformation.getBusinessIdentifier();
    }

    public byte[] getBusinessIdentifier()
    {
        return null != businessIdentifier ? this.businessIdentifier : eventInformation.getBusinessIdentifier();
    }
}
```

**AbstractEventInformation.java:**

```
@Embeddable
public abstract class AbstractEventInformation
{
    public abstract byte[] getBusinessIdentifier();
}
```

**OrderEventInformation.java:**

```
import com.google.common.primitives.Ints;

public class OrderEventInformation extends AbstractEventInformation
{
    private final int orderId;

    public OrderEventInformation(final int orderId)
    {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBusinessIdentifier()
    {
        return Ints.toByteArray(orderId);
    }
}
```

And this is the repository bound to `Event`:

**EventRepository.java:**

```
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long>
{
    int countByDepartmentAndBusinessIdentifier(Department department, byte[] businessIdentifier);
}
```

This structure works perfectly fine for saving entries into `events` table. But, for some reason, when I try to check for duplicates in MySQL using `countByDepartmentAndBusinessIdentifier`, this method always returns `0`.

I have integration tests running with H2 and in those tests the duplication check works just fine, it seems to be something specific with MySQL.

At first I thought it could be something related to the way my classes are structured, using `Embeddable`, abstract methods and so on, but I assume if that was the issue then saving values wouldn't work as well.

Would anyone have any idea of what I'm missing here?

BTW, I'm using Spring Boot version `1.3.5.RELEASE` along with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem had nothing to do with class hierarchy.

My `Event#businessIdentifier` is mapped as `byte(16)` to DB, and so, when I did `Ints.toByteArray(orderId)`, it would return a `byte[4]`. But in DB, all `businessIdentifiers` were stored as `byte[16]`, and so I was trying to do duplicate checks over byte arrays of different sizes.

The fix was changing `OrderEventInformation#getBusinessIdentifier` to right pad the `byte[]` with zeroes up to 16 positions. Then everything worked out just fine.